# HttpOnly cookie is not passed with request

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, cookies, httponly

I'm trying to store tokens in HttpOnly cookies, however I'm not really sure how to achieve that. First of all, my SpringBoot server is returning them like this

```
@PostMapping("/sign-in")
fun signIn(@RequestBody request: SignInRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): ResponseEntity<SignInResponse> {
    val signInResponse = signInService.signIn(request);
    val cookie = Cookie("Authorization", signInResponse.accessToken)
    cookie.isHttpOnly = true
    response.addCookie(cookie)
    return ResponseEntity.ok(signInResponse)
}
```

Then, in my Angular application I'm calling this API

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8081/api/auth/sign-in", {
      email: "user@user.com",
      password: "user"
    }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

It seems to be working fine, when I go to Network tab in browser, I can see that Cookie

[image]

However, then I try to call another endpoint, cookie is not passed

```
callWithCredentials() {
    this.httpClient.get(
      "http://localhost:8081/api/test",
      { withCredentials: true }
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Cross Origin

Calling a web API hosted on localhost is very likely to be a cross origin request, although your front-end and back-end are together on the same machine ("localhost"). Even if you configure cross-origin, some browsers do not support cross origin for javascript with "locahost" origin.

In this case , you will need to configure both "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" in your Springboot application. If you choose Chrome browser to test it out, use your javascript on some places other than "localhost".

## Debug

Go to Network tab and check the headers of the response. See if you have these in the response headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.com
```

## Change Javascript Origin

Modify the `host` file if you are using Windows. Resolve a domain such as "example.com" to "127.0.0.1".

Then you can open up "http://example.com:8080" to change javascript origin from localhost to "example.com"

## CORS Configuration in Springboot

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        /* Allow cookies */
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        /* This is your javascript origin */
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);

    }
// ...

}
```

---

A quick reminder here.

> public CorsConfiguration setAllowedOriginPatterns(@Nullable
> List allowedOriginPatterns)
> Alternative to setAllowedOrigins(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) that supports origins declared via wildcard patterns. In contrast to allowedOrigins which does support the special value "*", this property allows more flexible patterns, e.g. "https://*.domain1.com". Furthermore it always sets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to the matched origin and never to "*", nor to any other pattern, and therefore can be used in combination with setAllowCredentials(java.lang.Boolean) set to true.

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedOriginPatterns-java.util.List-)

Make sure you are using a recent version so you can use `.addAllowedOriginPattern("*")`, otherwise you have to use `.addAllowedOrigin("http://example.com:8080")` explicitly with your javascript domain.